# GridLayout item size is different

Tags: android

I am just messing with the `GridLayout` and I can't make it work. I created 8 buttons in the layout but they are not equal size. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3z4Q.png) is what it looks,
and here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.cegepgim.group.grid.MainActivity">

   <GridLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button> ..... <Button>// same buttons with different row and colums        

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:text="Button" />

    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove android:layout_gravity="fill"

Comment: or Add android:layout_rowWeight="1"

Comment: android:layout_rowWeight="1" worked. Thanks. Can you explain how?

Answer (score 0):

You must set layout_height to 0 for the weight to work